# How to disable collision between the player and the picked up object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I disabled collision between the player and the pickable objects to prevent jitteriness whenever the picked-up object is colliding with the player while moving.

```
 public void BreakConnection()

    {
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;

        currentlyPickedUpObject = null;

        lookObject = null;

        physicsObject.pickedUp = false;

        currentDist = 0;

        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1, layer2, false);
    }

    public void PickUpObject()
    {
        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1, layer2, true); 

        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();

        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;

        // currPicked = true;  

        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;

        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;

       
    }
```

I tried this  `Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1, layer2, true);`  when the object is picked up and `Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layer1, layer2, false);` when it is realised.

However, it is causing unwanted behaviour with other pickable objects. Is there a way to ONLY disable collision between the `currentlyPickedUpObject` and the player? not all the pickable objects?
I need `currentlyPickedUpObject` to collide with all other objects except the player. please help.

Comment: Or you could make it a trigger. Then physics doesn’t effect anything

Comment: make what trigger?

Comment: I want the picked up object to collide with other objects but I don't want it to collide with the player.

Comment: Well you can change the collision matrix.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did you can see in the code above. But all pickable objects have the same layer and I only want to disable collision only for the currently picked up object not all the pickable objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing whether layers can affect each other, change the layer of the object, you want to pick up, to another one, which never affects player's layer (as you have done by code or in collision layer matrix).

If your objects are on some important layer (let's say *pickable*), you could always duplicate your layer (*pickableIgnorePlayer*). If you have a lot of checks for layers in your code that can be a little tedious, but at the moment I can't see another way (maybe besides implementing own collisions for items).

To change layer of an object simply access gameObject's layer `gameObject.layer = layerIndex`. You can also use [layer's name](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html). You don't need to destroy layers (I'm not sure if you even can). What you probably mean is to change layer back to the original, which you do the same way, which is accessing `gameObject.layer`.

By duplicating layer I mean adding the new layer in the layers tab with the altered name and then making changes to your code if necessary. For eg. if your code was checking if layer was pickable, now check if layer is pickable or pickableIgnorePlayer if needed.

Comment: How can I add a new layer to an object in code and how to delete this layer when the object is dropped?

Comment: can you show me how to duplicate the layer ?

Comment: because yes, they are on important layer that I can't change.

Comment: @Okashi I edited my answer, check if that's what you wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

With the collision matrix you can define by layer with layers collide with which. Check: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html
You can change the layer at runtime so that you set your object to another interaction state, where the layer of the object and the player will not interact anymore, like so: `gameObject.layer = 8;`

Comment: but pickable objects have one important layer "pickable" in order for them to be picked up. can I add another layer to the objects that are picked up and then disable the layer when it is realised? A layer beside the pickable layer?